# Swift namespace conflict

Tags: swift, namespaces

Consider:

- A Swift framework called `FrameworkA` that defines the type `Thing`.
- A Swift framework called `FrameworkB` that also defines the type `Thing` and the type `FrameworkA`.
- An app that imports both frameworks in the same Swift file.

How do I reference `FrameworkA.Thing` in said file? The following line fails with `Thing is not a member of FrameworkA`.

```
let t : FrameworkA.Thing? = nil
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This appears to be a Swift bug. As a workaround, you can create a new Swift file in the app that imports only `FrameworkA` and defines a `typealias` for `Thing`:

```
import FrameworkA

typealias ThingA = Thing
```

Then in the file that needs to import both frameworks, you use `ThingA` instead of `FrameworkA.Thing`.

Comment: Thank you so so so much!

Comment: This saved me so much time, thank you!