# Class name conflict with class in Framework

Tags: ios, swift

In main project, I have a class named: Result.

And I import a third framework through Cocoapods which is also named Result. The Result framework has a class named Result.

In project, how can I use the Result class in Result framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774101/swift-namespace-conflict

Comment: It isn't the same.

Comment: @leizh00701 you can change your main class name to something else

Answer (score 23):

You need to put the package name in front of the class name.

```
ThirdPartyFrameworkName.Result
```

and

```
YourTargetName.Result
```

Comment: works, and I still needed to do the import in the beginning of the code file.